# collection of preference variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, collections, preference

I'm looking into importing my entire set of preference variables into a remote scope. Does PowerShell implement collections of variables? Is there a collection of preference variables? If so, would I be able to import the collection with $using: ?

Something like:

```
Begin { 
    $scriptblock = { 
        Try {
            $VerbosePreference = $Using:VerbosePreference
            $ErrorActionPreference = $Using:ErrorActionPreference
            ...
        } 
        Catch{ #Ignore these errors }

...
```

I'd like to import all the preference variables without specifying individually if possible...

Comment: Begin {
    $scriptblock = {
      Try {$VerbosePreference = $Using:VerbosePreference
      $ErrorActionPreference = $Using:ErrorActionPreference}
      Catch{
        #Ignore these errors
      }

Comment: I'd like to import all the preference variables without specifying individually if possible.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell (as of v5.1):

- doesn't implement *collections* of variables,
- and there is *no* programmatic way to *unambiguously and exhaustively* identify all preference variables.

<sup>For the current list of all preference variables, see [`Get-Help about_Preference_Variables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables).</sup>

That said, you can use wildcard expression `*Preference` with `Get-Variable` to locate at least *some* of the preference variables - and perhaps they cover your needs:

```
>  (Get-Variable *Preference).Name
ConfirmPreference
DebugPreference
ErrorActionPreference
InformationPreference
ProgressPreference
VerbosePreference
WarningPreference
WhatIfPreference
```

As stated, the results are neither guaranteed to be complete (e.g., `MaximumHistoryCount` is not matched), nor do they exclude potential false positives (nothing prevents you from defining variable `$FooPreference`, for instance).

If you're willing to extract all variable names from `about_Preference_Variables` *help topic* - which is not fully robust - see the bottom of this post.

Overall, the best *approximation* is probably the following command:

```
> Get-Variable | 
  Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -clike '*Preference' -or 
    ($_.Attributes -and $_.Options -notcontains 'ReadOnly') 
  } | % Name
ConfirmPreference
DebugPreference
ErrorActionPreference
InformationPreference
MaximumAliasCount
MaximumDriveCount
MaximumErrorCount
MaximumFunctionCount
MaximumHistoryCount
MaximumVariableCount
OutputEncoding
ProgressPreference
PSDefaultParameterValues
VerbosePreference
WarningPreference
WhatIfPreference
```

This relies on the assumption that only preference variables have (validation) *attributes*, which is *typically* true, but, again, you're free to define your own variables with validation attributes, which would then mistakenly be included too.

`$_.Options -notcontains 'ReadOnly'` weeds out *read-only* variables, because, by definition, they can't be *preference* variables if they cannot be modified.

---

As for using these variables in a remote command / a background job:

There is no elegant solution (and `$using:` only works with literal variable names), but you can try the following:

```
# Collect pref. variables, to the best of our ability.
$prefVarDefs = Get-Variable | ? { $_.Name -clike '*Preference' -or ($_.Attributes -and $_.Options -notcontains 'ReadOnly') }  

# Pass them to the background/remote script block and have them
# assigned there.
Start-Job { $args | % { set-variable $_.Name $_.Value }; ... } -Args $prefVarDefs
```

Note that `Start-Job` is used as an example (because it can be run without remoting and in a non-elevated session), but the same rules apply as with `Invoke-Command`, for instance, and the same technique can be used with the latter.

---

Another option is to **parse the `about_Preference_Variables` help topic**, which is somewhat brittle however, because it:

- relies on the topic's specific formatting
- relies on the topic to be both complete and accurate.

```
(Get-Help about_Preference_Variables) -creplace '(?s)\A.*?\r?\n +?Variable +Default Value\r?\n +?-+ +-+\r?\n(.+?)\r?\n\r?\n.*\Z', '$1'  -split '\r?\n' | % { (-split $_)[0] }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm rather surprised. I will see about suggesting the implementation of collections like these on Powershell User Voice. Thanks again.

Comment: @M.Anselmi My pleasure. I've updated the answer with a better _approximation_ of finding all preference variables, but it's not robust. Asking for an explicit feature at https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell is the right approach. Once you've posted your suggestion, I encourage you to post the specific link here, so that future readers can easily vote on it too, if they're interested.

Comment: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/17407222-powershell-and-collections-in-particular-collect